# TableViewCells deleted after leaving the page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView and you can add/delete cells if you like. There are 3 pages. The second page allows the user to add cells to the table view, which is on the third page. The first page is just a navigation page. If i add any number of cells to the table view, i can see them on the 3rd page fine! I can return to the second page, and then return back to the 3rd page. And the cells will still be there, but if i go to the 2nd page, then the 1st, and back to the table view, all the cells are gone!! How can i fix this? My Code for navigating through the pages is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender{
RootViewController * black = [[BlackFacePlateViewControlller alloc]init];
black.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:black animated:YES];
[black release];
}
```

and:

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you managing the model that is backing the `UITableView`?

Answer (score 1):

Kurt, you have to understand something about persistence on not just the iPhone, but any system. You most likely have an array that is loaded into the table, but when the controller class containing that array is dismissed (as you have it with `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`), the chance is more likely than not that dealloc (or in the case of ARC, a mass release of your objects) will be called on that controller, and your array will be set to nil and reclaimed but the system.  You need a storage mechanism, whether that's a plist, a specific file format, or XML, you need some means of retrieving the datasource array even after it's been destroyed.

I myself am now  huge advocate of the plist route, as they're just so convenient and easy to use, and they can be edited with absolutely massive amounts of data with little side effects.

Comment: alright, I totally understand! Thanks a bunch for the help! I am going to try the plist route like you said!

Comment: one more quick question, do i have to add the cell's text, and the cells image to a plist? If so, do i need different plists for the text and for the image? Thanks :D

Comment: Don't save images or the cell's text, just save the array.

Comment: oh.. okay, what goes into the array? The cell's text right? Thanks again for the help!